# AddRedirectToHttps() doesn't redirect to Https

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-core

The [Enforcing SSL in a ASP.NET Core App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl) guide on MSDN, tells me to add the following code to my `Configure` method in the `Startup` class, in order to redirect all `http` request to `https`:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
       .AddRedirectToHttps();

    app.UseRewriter(options);
```

Having added the code in the correct place, and testing a http request in debug mode, I get a `connection reset` error in chrome:

```
This site can’t be reached

The connection was reset.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

I'm trying to access the same URL (including port.. which I think is where I might be going wrong?) that I would if I was using https... I.E, I'm typing `http://localhost:44376` instead of `https://localhost:44376` into my address bar.

A slimmed down version of my `Configuration` method looks like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    var options = new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRedirectToHttps();

    app.UseRewriter(options);

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseIdentity();

    app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions()
    {
        AppId = Configuration["Authentication_FacebookAppId"],
        AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication_FacebookAppSecret"]
    });

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As this [github post](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/898) confirms, I was on the right lines thinking it was probably the port that was causing the issue. (Essentially, you can't listen for `http` and `https` requests on the same port.)

The fix for me was actually three-fold:

Firstly, you need to be careful how your running your app in development. When running visual studio on windows, the default is to startup using IIS / IIS Express. This causes a problem because it uses the application url defined in the project settings, rather than the urls we try to pass to kestrel via the startup class. (It's the `applicationUrl` defined in the `iisSettings` section of `launchSettings.json`)

If you expand the drop down on the `start` button inside Visual Studio, you should see an option with your project name, this starts your application using `Kestrel` via the dotnet CLI.

Secondly, you need to define two url's for kestrel to listen on, one for `http` and the other for `https`. This is done by simply passing in two url's, with different ports to the `UseUrls()` method in `main()`:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel(options => {
        options.UseHttps(certFile, certPass);
    })
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseUrls("https://*:44388", "http://*:8080")
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseApplicationInsights()
    .Build();
```

Finally, if your not using the default https port (443), you'll need to specify which port you want kestrel to redirect `http` request too. To do this, simply overload the `AddRedirectToHttps()` method, by passing in a `status code` and the port your wanting to redirect too. I've used the status code `301` to permanently redirect to `https`.

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
.AddRedirectToHttps(301, 44388);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar issue with the usage of `.AddRedirectToHttps()`. But I found out that it might not set the port correctly to the default SSL port 443.

Use `AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent()` instead!, because it will default the port to 443.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Redirects all HTTP requests to HTTPS
    if (env.IsProduction())
    {
        app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent());
    }

     ....
}
```